# Call a method inside the select part of a LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following linq query:

```
var file = (from p in database.tblFile
            join o in database.tblFileVersion on p.fldFileID equals o.fldFileID
            join t in database.tblFileAttachments on p.fldFileID equals t.fldFileID
            where p.fldFileID == team.Key
            where o.fldVersionNo == highestVersion
            select new UserDashboardFile
            {
                Filename = p.fldFilename,
                VersionNumber = o.fldVersionNo,
                FileID = team.Key,
                Type = GetFileType(t.fldTableName),
            }).Single();
```

GetFileType is a method that returns an enumeration type. There is no syntax error but when I run the project (it is an mvc 4 web project) I receive the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'DCIS.Code.UserDashboardFileType GetFileType(System.String)' method,
>   and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I imagine that this query cannot be translated into a t-sql query but I do not know how to change my query in order to avoid the above error. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can select anonymous object first and then construct `UserDashboardFile`.

```
var file = (from p in database.tblFile
            join o in database.tblFileVersion on p.fldFileID equals o.fldFileID
            join t in database.tblFileAttachments on p.fldFileID equals t.fldFileID
            where p.fldFileID == team.Key
            where o.fldVersionNo == highestVersion
            select new 
            {
                Filename = p.fldFilename,
                VersionNumber = o.fldVersionNo,
                FileID = team.Key,
                FldTableName = t.fldTableName
            }).Single();
var udFile = new UserDashboardFile { ..., Type = GetFileType(file.FldTableName) };
```

Also you can call `.AsEnumerable()` before select to prevent `GetFileType` to be translated in sql.