# Linq to Entities Function to return whether integer parameter is in certain range

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, sql-function

I have a set of 5 parameters, two upper limits and two lower limits of a range and the actual value. In my Linq-to-Entites query I would like to be able to return an integer depending on where the value falls within the limits in the range.

For example:

```
if (value > highest limit || value < lowest limit) return 6;
if (value < highest limit && value > 2nd high limit || value > lowest limit && value < 2nd lowest limit) return 5;
else if (value < 2nd highest limit && value > 2nd lowest limit) return 4;
```

the query would be:

```
var list = from item in ObjectContext.Plants
           where item.ID == ID
           select new Model()
           {
               ID = item.ID,
               Name = item.Name,
               Status = CalculateWhereInRange(item.numericValue, item.UpperHighLimit, item.LowerHighLimit, item.UpperLowLimit, item.LowerLowLimit)
           };
return list;
```

**EDIT**

The query is being called on the server side, and passes the data back to the viewmodel.
Can this be achieved with a stored function or sql function?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Also your query won't work because linq-to-entities query provider don't know how to translate `CalculateWhereInRange`

Comment: That is my question - how can I do this? Stored function? Sql funtion on my DB? I can't think how this could actually be achieved using the tools available.

Comment: Similar problem and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13332986/1009661

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method `GetRangeStatus` to the item's class itself. Then you can use it like this

```
var list = from item in ObjectContext.Plants
           where item.ID == ID
           select new Model()
           {
               ID = item.ID,
               Name = item.Name,
               Status = item.GetRangeStatus() // <====
           };
return list;
```

There is no need to pass any parameters, since all needed values are stored in`item`.

Comment: Maybe if it is a partial class? Otherwise you can make it an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Store your five parameters:

```
    item.numericValue, item.UpperHighLimit, item.LowerHighLimit, item.UpperLowLimit, item.LowerLowLimit
```

In five properties on your Model class, then in the constructor of model you can apply the logic of CalculateWhereInRange()

Like

```
    var list = from item in ObjectContext.Plants
    where item.ID == ID
    select new Model()
       {
           ID = item.ID,
           Name = item.Name,
           NumericValue = item.numericValue, 
           UpperHighLimit = item.UpperHighLimit
           LowerHighLimit = item.LowerHighLimit
           UpperLowLimit =  item.UpperLowLimit
           LowerLowLimit = item.LowerLowLimit
       };



     public class Model()
     {
           public int UpperHighLimit {get;set;} //And all the others
           public Model()
           {
              //Do Calculations here with your 5 properties
           }
     }
```

Comment: I want to get the values before I pass back the data to the viewmodel (this would all be happening on the domain server side, rather than the client side)

Comment: Ah, I see. If i remember right, you can use the (if x) ? y : z logic inside your Linq2Sql Status assignment, but it'd be really ugly

Comment: Yes, I can see how it would be very messy, trying to keep away from that!

Comment: @xhedgepigx Yeah, the anonymous types solution that 2kay linked to looks like it might be what yer lookin for